# Why was std::ranges::less introduced?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

On [cppreference on `std::ranges::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/less), in **notes** we can see that:

> Unlike `std::less`, `std::ranges::less` requires all six comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==` and `!=` to be valid (via the `totally_ordered_with` constraint).

But... why? Why would we use `std::ranges::less{}` instead of `std::less{}`? What is the practical situation in which we want to `less{}` only if there are other comparison operators defined, not only the `<` one?

Comment: I'm not sure what all the small differences are, but at least it's properly constrained.

Comment: @chris but simply constraining a template cannot be a sole reason to duplicate every single one, can it? Plus, what is the purpose of those additional constraints?

Comment: Specifically about `<` vs. everything, I seem to remember some consensus that it's rather silly for types to have `<` without having the others. There have always been options for using the comparator arguments instead of overloading one on the type and not having the due diligence to overload the others. The type can also just as well provide a properly named comparator alongside the class (e.g., a class `Student` with a  nested `NameComparator` struct). That said, this "proliferation of bad types" reasoning might as well be 100% speculation because vague memory is a terrible source.

Comment: (And of course, no code is broken because these are all offered in addition to the old APIs, so this was the perfect time to make any changes that "should have" been there all along.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the practical situation in which we want to less{} only if there are other comparison operators defined, not only the < one?

Not everything about the Ranges library is based purely on what is "practical". Much of it is about making the language and library make logical sense.

Concepts as a language feature gives the standard library the opportunity to define *meaningful* combinations of object features. To say that a type has an `operator<` is useful from the purely practical perspective of telling you what operations are available to it. But it doesn't really say anything meaningful about the type.

If a type is totally ordered, then that logically means that you could use any of the comparison operators to compare two objects of that type. Under the idea of a total order, `a < b` and `b > a` are equivalent statements. So it makes sense that if code is restricted to types that provide a total order, that code should be permitted to use either statement.

`ranges::less::operator()` does not *use* any operator other than `<`. But this function is constrained to types modelling the `totally_ordered` concept. This constraint exists because that's what `ranges::less` is *for*: comparing types which are totally ordered. It could have a more narrow constraint, but that would be throwing away any meaning provided by total ordering.

It also prevents you from exposing arbitrary implementation details to users. For example, let's say that you've got a template that takes some type `T` and you want to use `T` in a `ranges::less`-based operation. If you constrain this template to just having an `operator<`, then you have effectively put your implementation into the constraint. You no longer have the freedom for the implementation to switch to `ranges::greater` internally. Whereas if you had put `std::totally_ordered` in your constraint, you would make it clear to the user what they need to do while giving yourself the freedom to use whatever functors you need.

And since `operator<=>` exists and makes it easy to implement the ordering operators in one function, there's no *practical* downside. Well, except for code that has to compile on both C++17 and C++20.

Essentially, you shouldn't be writing types that are "ordered" by just writing `operator<` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell based on the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1291r0.pdf) the idea is to just simplify the design of the function objects. `std::less` is a template class which requires a template parameter and represents a homogeneous comparison. This template parameter can be omitted to default to `std::less<void>` which allows heterogeneous comparisons. The argument seems to be that the homogeneous case is unnecessary as it's handled fine by the heterogeneous approach, so the design can be simplified considerably and a class template isn't needed at all.

As to why the other operators besides `operator<` are required I'm not completely sure. My best guess is that this is just part of what it means to have a total order defined in C++ between two, possibly different, types.